# Suggest product catalog script/framework in PHP which doesn't displays product price

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am new to web development and have this project in hand where in I have to build a product catalogue. I don't want any cart functionality or other such features, I just want to display the products,their specifications and images etc. on the website and give my client an admin panel to manage products.
Now I looked into various PHP shopping cart scripts but couldn't find a way to remove price info from the display. I am not experienced enough in web development to make a product catalogue from scratch so if you guys could point me out in right direction I would be very grateful. If you could give me link to some shopping cart or cataloguing script or any other way to accomplish the task it would help me out a lot..

Thanks in advance to all those who reply.

Comment: No offense, but if you are unable to **modify the template** displaying the products and their price, then you should probably not be working for a client yet.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you can look at [phpMyDirectory](http://www.phpmydirectory.com/), if that solution will suit you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **Prestashop**. I think it is the best and one of the most advanced PHP based catalog CMS around.